# Working of websocket services in clustered deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, websocket, redis, microservices

Lets say I have a websocket implemented in springboot. The architecture is microservice. I have deployed the service in kubernetes cluster and I have 2 running instance of the service, the socket implementation is using stomp and redis as broker.

1. Now the first connection is created between a client and one of the service. Does all the data flow occur through the client and the connected service? Would the other service also have a connection? Incase the current service goes down would the other service open up a connection?
2. Now lets say I'am sending some data back to the client which comes through a kafka topic. One of the either service could read it. If then would either of them be able to send the data back to the client?

Can someone help me understand these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A websocket is a permanent connection. After opening it, it will be routed through kubernetes to a fixed pod. No other pod will receive the connection.
If the pod goes down, the connection is terminated.

If a new connection is created, for example by a different user, it may be routed to a different pod.

What data is transmitted, for example with kafka as source, is not relevant in this context. It could be anything.

Comment: The data transmitted here means  the socket is listening to pod excepts some response send back . Since only one pod will have the connection and multiple instances running means that the listener in any of the service can read data from kafka topic right. if the service that is not currently has the session receives the data then what can we do to send the data to the required socket.

Comment: You can use another kafka topic to broadcast the received data from the websocket.

Comment: Iam not trying to broadacast but send to an individual user.

Comment: That is not related to websocket nor kubernetes. please accept the answer and create a new question regarding your business requirements, if necessary.